# Postgres insert returning Raw Django Model query not working?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-postgresql

I have a simple model I am inserting into.  I am using the following syntax:

```
m = Model.objects.raw("insert into my_model (col) values ('test') returning *")
```

In postgres, this returns the identical columns that :
select * from my_model where col = 'test' limit 1;
would return.  However, I am unable to get this to work. I had to resort to:

```
m Model(col='test')
m.save()
m = Model.objects.get(id = m.id)
```

I could also try the raw cursor syntax, but, it seems that the raw should work because the columns being returned map directly on to the model whose raw() I am using.

Comment: `m = Model.objects.create(col='test'); print(m.pk)`

Comment: this works.  but, i have triggers that do things to data when data is inserted.  i want to get a copy of that 'new' data when the insert happens.  for example, i have a trigger that inserts the timestamp of the insert and who did the insert.  your idea works if everything is modeled in django, in my case, i do lots of data manipulation outside the scope of django.  the main point is that insert ... returning returns a data set, if i did a select from table the objects.raw() would work. the raw() command seems to be outwitting itself.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but once you save the model the reference will reflect the _saved_ instance; so if you have any db-side triggers they will be fired and the resulting object (row reference) will show the effects of those cursors/stored procedures.

Comment: The point is I can run a select * from my_model where using the Model's raw() method.  Since insert into my_model returning * returns the same data that select * returns, I would expect the Model's raw() method to perform the same for both.  It doesn't.  I think it is a bug.